# How to select the left audio channel with ffmpeg and downmix to mono?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have an old "stereo" movie as a mp4 file.

The sound is only in the left channel, the right channel is silent.

I'd like to use ffmpeg to copy the video stream :

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i video.mp4 -c:v copy ...
```

and convert the audio to mono by selecting only the left channel :

```
-map_channel 0.1.0 -map_channel -1
```

But that didn't change anything :-(

What is the correct ffmpeg command line for that ?

Is it also possible to do that whithout re-encoding ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are at least two methods to select the left audio channel and output as mono.

## Using `-map_channel`

Assuming the input only contains audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input -map_channel 0.0.0 output
```

- The first number is the *input file id*: you only have one input so that will be `0`. The second number is the *stream specifier*: if the audio is the second stream, such is often the case in a typical video file, then you would use `1` instead. The third number is the *channel number*: in a stereo input the first channel is usually the Front Left, and the second is usually the Front Right.
- If you want the right channel instead use `-map_channel 0.0.1`.
- If the input contains video, then the audio will likely (but not always) be listed as the second stream, so you would need to use `0.1.0` instead.

## Using pan audio filter

```
ffmpeg -i input -af "pan=mono|c0=FL" output
```

- Alternatively, you could use `pan=mono|c0=c0`.
- If you want the right channel instead use `pan=mono|c0=FR` (or `pan=mono|c0=c1`).

#### Also see

- [pan audio filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channel Manipulation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation)

Comment: Hi, you said "Assuming the input only contains audio:".
The problem is that my file contains both video and audio :)

Comment: @SebMa This one reason why you need to include the complete console output from your commands so the answers can be more accurate and less based on assumptions. I edited the answer mentioning video.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to give it but ffmpeg didn't give any error anyway.
In my question, you can notice I used `-map_channel 0.1.0` but this is not enough to get both channels point to the left one.

Comment: @SebMa Using `-map_channel 0.1.0` works for me to make a mono audio file from the left channel of a stereo input (with video as the first stream).

Comment: I think it only works for audio files. For videos, you have to add `-ac 1`

Comment: Hi, I think the best would be that I give the youtube URL of the video that I'm trying to convert to a mono video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9dPJCFXAes

Comment: @SebMa What are you using to get a local copy of the video?

Comment: `youtube-dl`, but don't bother.


I solved the pb. by replacing :


`-map_channel 0.1.0 -map_channel -1`


which actually muted the second audio channel, instead of just using :


`-map_channel 0.1.0`


Thanks for your help :)

Comment: **Note:** You **cannot** use `-c copy` (codec copy) after the `-map_channel`. Doing so will ignore your changes. You must let it re-encode your audio.

Comment: >  if the audio is the second stream, such is often the case in a typical video file, then you would use 1 instead.

How can you tell, if your audio is in the first stream or in the second/other stream?

Answer (score 1):

@LordNeckbeard : Found the reason why my resulting file had only audio on the left channel like my source file.

It was because I used :

`-map_channel 0.1.0 -map_channel -1`

which muted the second audio channel, instead of just using :

`-map_channel 0.1.0`

Thanks for your help :)